# ffmpeg Adding transpose filter to -filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have the following ffmpeg command that takes images adds a fade-in fade-out effect and outputs a video. I'm trying to add "transpose=1" to rotate the video, but can't wrap my head around using -filter_complex

Here's the command working without the transpose:

```
-loop 1 -t 2 -i "image.jpg" -loop 1 -t 2 -i "image2.jpg" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=2,fade=t=out:st=1.5:d=0.5[v0];[1:v]trim=duration=2,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=1.5:d=0.5[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0, scale=1080:1920,format=yuv420p[v]" -map [v] -c:v libx264 preset fast -r 30 video.mp4
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You can simply add `,transpose=1` after `format=yuv420p`: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2 -i "image.jpg" -loop 1 -t 2 -i "image2.jpg" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=2,fade=t=out:st=1.5:d=0.5[v0];[1:v]trim=duration=2,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=1.5:d=0.5[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0, scale=1080:1920,format=yuv420p,transpose=1[v]" -map [v] -c:v libx264 -preset fast -r 30 video.mp4`

Comment: That was easy! Thanks